# Proximal Mapping of $\frac{1}{2}\Vert Ax - b \Vert_2^2$

Tags: reference-request, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

The question is self-explanatory, I need to find the proximal mapping of $\frac{1}{2} \Vert Ax - b \Vert_2^2$ where $A$ in a given rectangular matrix and $b$ is a given vector of appropriate size.

Please note that I don't need any proof or justification whatsoever, just naming the proximal mapping would suffice, albeit perhaps kindly with a credible reference. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Given $y$, the proximal map at $y$ is the unique minimizer of the function
$$x\mapsto \tfrac{1}{2}\|Ax-b\|_2^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}\|x-y\|_2^2.$$
Do you know how to take the derivative of this function, set it equal to $0$, and solve for $x$?
As for references, check the books by Beck and by Bauschke-Combettes.

Comment: Yup! Thanks for the comment. It's a simple LSP (How did I miss that?). Here's the solution: $(I + A^HA)^{-1}(x+A^Hy)$.

Comment: And by the superscript $H$ I mean complex transpose (or Hermitian transpose).

Comment: @max_zorn Just edited the question.

Comment: Thanks @Erfan that was fun!